# module sklearn has no attribute ''__version__"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-0f8fe9defe1d> in <module>
  1 import sklearn
 ----> 2 print(sklearn.__version__)

AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute '__version__'
```

how to resolve this issue? I have sklearn, scipy installed on my anaconda but still the error appears

Comment: What return do you get from `dir(sklearn)`?

Comment: Could it be that you named one of yur scripts `sklearn.py` ? Anwyay: you can check what you REALLY imported just replacing `print(sklearn.__version__)` with `print(sklearn)`.

Comment: I had the same issue because of mixed-up environment of `conda` and `pip`. If you use `conda` you should also install scikit-learn via `conda` and not `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are on Windows make sure you have the correct environment selected where you have installed the package.

Secondly, install the package with `pip install scikit-learn` via command prompt.
If that doesn't work you will have to install te package via [this website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the command:

```
 conda install scikit-learn
```